# 18.04 LTS - after update partitions in "read only" mode

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, files, read-only

After an Ubuntu update, my partition on HDD is in "read-only" mode.

Ubuntu system is on SSD and Home folder works fine (I mean full access).

I tried to change the permission but it is not possible (also with `sudo chgrp adm /media/...` command) - without success.

The system file is NFTS, I've got a dual boot with Win10.

Does anyone have any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like Win10 fastboot is keeping the partition in an unclean state on shutdown. Have you tried to disable Windows fastboot by booting into windows and holding shift while selecting shutdown to disable fastboot temporarily then boot into linux and try mounting the partition again? This should allow you to mount the ntfs partition in linux as rw.

Comment: yeah, that was the case! I uncheck fast boot und now everything is back to normal. thank you very much for help!

Comment: You're very welcome. glad to help!